# git commit not working on directory

Tags: git, github, git-svn

First of all, I am new to git and I'm sorry in advance if my question seems foolish to you.

I'm working on the files inside a directory say

FrmMain/FrmMain/Forms/ [Has approx 100 files]

I have initialized the git at the Parent Directory i.e. first FrmMain

Now when I try to `git commit` the modified files inside the Forms directory, after I have applied the `git add .`, it doesn't commit the changes.

To be further clear, here is the sequence of commands that I'm applying:

[image]

What I'm getting is: It doesn't bring the folder to staging area. Any Idea how may I get this to work?

Comment: Hmmm, works for me.  Can you try adding an individual file and show the results?

Comment: Have you checked your `.gitignore` or `.git/info/excludes` files?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have created in repo in

```
//USMAN/SharedDocs/faisal/FrmMain
```

But you must have a git repo in `//USMAN/SharedDocs/faisal` (a `.git` folder), since we see a `(master)` branch in your prompt.

That means the git repo in `//USMAN/SharedDocs/faisal` will **ignore** the *nested* repo in `//USMAN/SharedDocs/faisal/FrmMain`.

You should go to //USMAN/SharedDocs/faisal/FrmMain in oder to do a `git add .`